# AWS S3 Direct Upload Javascript failure

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, amazon-s3

I manage a site written in Ruby on Rails, Javascript, and C that's been up for a few years, and allows users to upload data files that we process. I use the s3_direct_upload gem to bypass our web server and process the file asynchronously, providing progress updates to the client.

Recently we have a user that is no longer able to upload files though he had been able to in the past. No other users are experiencing the issue. He is running Chrome on Windows, and thankfully was willing to get a screen print of the Java console when the error occurs. It is below.

[image]

The Javascript code in question is as follows with the error getting called on `s3_upload_failed`, `content.filename` has the correct filename, and `content.error_thrown` is blank:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var upload_names = [];

  $('#new_ride_menu, #new_ride_button').S3Uploader(
    {
      remove_completed_progress_bar: false,
      progress_bar_target: $('.ride-upload-progress'),
      before_add: validateFile,
      expiration: null
    }
  );
  $('#new_ride_menu, #new_ride_button').bind('s3_uploads_start', function(e, content) {
    $('#ride-upload-modal').appendTo('body').modal('show');
  });
  // one upload is complete
  $('#new_ride_menu, #new_ride_button').bind('s3_upload_complete', function(e, content) {
    upload_names.push(content.file);
  });
  // all uploads are complete
  $('#new_ride_menu, #new_ride_button').bind('s3_uploads_complete', function(e, content) {
    // HANDLE SERVER COMMS AND PROCESSING
  });
  $('#new_ride_menu, #new_ride_button').bind('s3_upload_failed', function(e, content) {
    $.post('/logs', {level: 'warn', message: 'Error uploading file: '+content.filename});
    return alert(content.filename + ' failed to upload');
  });
});
```

I'm attempting to replicate this error with no success. I've tried:

- Disabling Javascript
- Disabling cookies
- Blocking third party cookies
- Turned off unsandboxed plugin access
- Turned off clipboard access

Does this set of errors look familiar to anyone? Is this a client side configuration issue? Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tough to tell from the console but the failed OPTIONS request makes me think that it's related to a CORS issue. My only other thought is the user has a chrome extension installed that alters request headers. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @DanHilton. My first thought was CORS, but that turned out to be OK. I'll include the extensions concept in my investigation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After being unable to diagnose with more info, I got on the phone with the customer and asked them to bring up the site on IE. That worked and therefore proved something was amiss with Chrome.

Turns out they were using two Chrome instances, one for work and one for home. The home version played nicely with my site, however the work version had some very restrictive options. In the end, the solution was to make sure the customer was using their home version of Chrome.